# Should I install Ubuntu as 32 bit or 64 bit since i have 3GB ram?

Tags: system-installation

I have a Compaq Presario CQ60 with 3 GB ram and 32 bit Operating System and i don't if i should 32 bit since it say 2 GB or less ram. So should i pic 32 bit or 64 Bit.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a 64 bit capable cpu and specs that support it, definitely as 64 bit handles multithreading/multitasking a LOT better